# ValueError(f"Dotenv specified in config but not found at path: {env_path}")

Tags: python, brownie

I am trying to run this contract but I get the following error:

```sh
(base) elly@elly-Lenovo-G50-80:~/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/brownie_fund_me$ brownie run scripts/deploy.py
Brownie v1.19.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

File "brownie/_cli/main.py", line 64, in main
importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 42, in main
active_project.load_config()
File "brownie/project/main.py", line 474, in load_config
_load_project_config(self._path)
File "brownie/_config.py", line 199, in _load_project_config
raise ValueError(f"Dotenv specified in config but not found at path: {env_path}")
ValueError: Dotenv specified in config but not found at path: /home/elly/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/brownie_fund_me/.env
```

Below I added all the files:

1. FundMe.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

contract FundMe {
using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;

mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
address[] public funders;
address public owner;
AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;

// if you're following along with the freecodecamp video
// Please see https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/fund_me
// to get the starting solidity contract code, it'll be slightly different than this!
constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function fund() public payable {
    uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10**18;
    require(
        getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD,
        "You need to spend more ETH!"
    );
    addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    funders.push(msg.sender);
}

function getVersion() public view returns (uint256) {
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
        0xbb18dd19aeda4a56a474a5e795e826de
    );
    return priceFeed.version();
}

function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
        0xbb18dd19aeda4a56a474a5e795e826de
    );
    (, int256 answer, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
}

// 1000000000
function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount)
    public
    view
    returns (uint256)
{
    uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
    uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1000000000000000000;
    return ethAmountInUsd;
}

function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
    // minimumUSD
    uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10**18;
    uint256 price = getPrice();
    uint256 precision = 1 * 10**18;
    // return (minimumUSD * precision) / price;
    // We fixed a rounding error found in the video by adding one!
    return ((minimumUSD * precision) / price) + 1;
}

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
    msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);

    for (
        uint256 funderIndex = 0;
        funderIndex < funders.length;
        funderIndex++
    ) {
        address funder = funders[funderIndex];
        addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
    }
    funders = new address[](0);
}

}
```

2. Brownie-config.yaml
   dependencies:

```
smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1
compiler:
solc:
remappings:
    '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1'
    dotenv: .env
    wallets:
    from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

3. Deploy.py

```
from brownie import FundMe
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account

def deploy_fund_me():
account=get_account()
fund_me=FundMe.deploy({"from": account})
print(f"Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")

def main():
deploy_fund_me()
```

4. Helpful_scripts.py

```
from brownie import network, config, accounts

def get_account():
if network.show_active()=="development":
return accounts[0]
else:
return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
```

Comment: Where is your .env file stored at?

Comment: /home/elly/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/brownie_fund_me/tests/ .env